# Is it possible to add laravel paginate() function in select?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code, Is it possible to append laravel paginate function `paginate(15)` with select query?
I am asking because I have getting an error running below query.
`Call to a member function paginate() on array`.
Could you please help me to solve this issue?

```
$select = DB::connection('mysql2')->select("SELECT c.company, c.id FROM register_companies c 
            INNER JOIN register_cities rc ON rc.id = c.register_city_id
            WHERE rc.title = '" . urldecode($city) . "' 
            AND UPPER(SUBSTR(c.company,1, 1)) NOT RLIKE '^[A-Z]' 
            AND c.status = 'online' 
            ORDER BY c.company")->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get pagination you have to use Laravel's query builder, so your query will look like this:

```
DB::connection("mysql2")
                ->table("register_companies")
                ->join("register_cities", "register_cities.id", "=", "register_companies.register_city_id")
                ->whereRaw("register_cities.title=? 
                            and UPPER(SUBSTR(register_companies.company,1, 1)) NOT RLIKE '^[A-Z]' 
                            and register_companies.status = 'online'", [urldecode($city)])
                ->orderBy("register_companies.company")
                ->selectRaw("register_companies.company, register_companies.id")
                ->paginate(15);
```